# Javascript / jQuery Parallel Resize Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am looking for a plugin which can resize two parallel divs at the same time in the opposite direction.

```
<div class='one'></div>
<div class='handle'></div>
<div class='two'></div>
```

Assume the divs are floated next to each other.

When a user drags .handle to the right it should make .two smaller and .one bigger.

I've tried writing a basic plugin but I can't account for all browsers etc.

What I'm really trying to do if anyone is interested is resize multiple CKEditor instances. .one and .two would contain an instance of CKEditor and handle would need to resize them in parallel.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need is the plugin called "jQuery UI resizable".

There is an example of what your are trying to do on the samples page: [Synchronous Resize](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#synchronous-resize)

Comment: Thanks, I sort of ended up doing this but syncronous resize isnt appropriate because it resizes both divs the same way. I needed to resize one div smaller while the other div gets bigger.

Answer (score 1):

In my application, I had two divs side by side with same height, so I used jquery UI to make one resizable, and then using the size information from first div to set the position for the second one. This was done in the resize callback function.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".one" ).resizable({
        handles: "e",
        resize: function(event, ui) {
            $( ".two" ).css("left", $(this).width() );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```